# type mismatch in pytorch forward method

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to augment the MNIST found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/mnist) by loading my own data.
To do so I have numpy arrays `training_x`, `training_y` which I transform as follows:

```
training_X = torch.from_numpy(training_X)
training_y = torch.from_numpy(training_y)
```

[Note that the original `training_y` is the output of scikit-learn's LabelEncoder]

and add to the DataLoader by doing:

```
torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(training_X, training_y)
```

when training I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: addmm_ received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, int, torch.cuda.FloatTensor, torch.FloatTensor), but expected one of:
* (torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (float beta, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (float alpha, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (float beta, torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (float alpha, torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
* (float beta, float alpha, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, torch.cuda.FloatTensor, !torch.FloatTensor!)
v * (float beta, float alpha, torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor mat1, torch.cuda.FloatTensor mat2)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (int, int, !torch.cuda.FloatTensor!, !torch.FloatTensor!)
```

I have tried changing the input tensors to float, double and long but it seems I am still missing something crucial.

How can I get the model to accept my input?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the fourth argument you are providing is a `torch.FloatTensor` but it should be a `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.

Did you try calling `.cuda()` on that argument?

See [`torch.Tensor.cuda()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/tensors.html?highlight=cuda#torch.Tensor.cuda)